# Simple calculator always return 0

Tags: c#

In my C# application I want to implement a simple calculation. I got this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int percentField;
    int priceField;
    int result;

    percentField = int.Parse(txtPercentNew.Text);
    priceField = int.Parse(txtPriceNew.Text);

    result = priceField / 100 * percentField;

    MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
}
```

But the problem is the `MessageBox` displays me `0`. I can't figure out why.
Can someone please give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're dividing an int by an int. Check out integer division more closely and you'll see your problem.

Comment: Next time, you should provide some test values / results so the problem becomes even more clear...

Comment: @Tsasken I will remember for next time, thank you :)

Comment: @Dan Okay, thanks. I will have a closer look at it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your variables are integers, which means that `/` performs [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html). Unless `priceField` is at least equal to 100 you will always get 0 as the result.

You can correct the problem by casting `priceField` to a floating point type before dividing:

```
(double)priceField / 100 * percentField;
```

However, this will not work while `result` is of type `int` because the compiler wants to protect you from inadvertent rounding errors. So you either have to cast back to an integer (losing precision due to rounding):

```
result = (int)((double)priceField / 100 * percentField);
```

or else make `result` be a `double` as well.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the input. Nice to know. But if I use "double" it says that I use the wrong format

Comment: Ah nice. It sounds more logical than before! Thank you very much :) I will have a closer look at integer division :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using integers instead of floating point numbers.
As a consequence, rounding off occurs during calculation.

Use `float` or `double` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your `priceField` is less then `100` and since you doing *integer division*, it creates `0` as a result.

From [`/ Operator (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx)

> **When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer.** For
>   example, the result of 7 / 3 is 2. To determine the remainder of 7 /
>   3, use the remainder operator (%). To obtain a quotient as a rational
>   number or fraction, give the dividend or divisor type float or type
>   double. You can assign the type implicitly if you express the dividend
>   or divisor as a decimal by putting a digit to the right side of the
>   decimal point, as the following example shows.

Just cast one of your variables to floating point type like;

```
result = priceField / 100d * percentField;
```

or

```
result = (double)priceField / 100 * percentField;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are working with only integers, try

```
double result;    
result = priceField / (double)100 * percentField;
```

In your code, you are dividing by 100. Which means every int you are going to divide less than 100 will result in a value between [0 - 1]. When implicitly casting to an int, the result will be floored. Therefor, a 0.1 will become 0 - a 0.9 will become 0 - ...

Answer (score 0):

try cast to `double`, because you're working with integers it results in 0.

example [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/divide)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using `int` for each value.

Change result to a `double` and try this:

```
result = (double)priceField / 100 * percentField;
```

It should work; however, if you want to do this properly I recommend you read about [MidpointRounding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).