# Why does this calculation keep returning 0

Tags: c#, methods

I have a program that needs to work the percentage of parcels in that category. There is 8 different category's and each of them should give a percentage but they all return 0% even if 100% of the packages are in that category. I have a method that I call to work out the percentages.

Here is where the method is called(there is another 7 instances of this)

```
Console.WriteLine("\nCategory 1: {0} packets. {1} %", cat1, workout(cat1, totalpackets));
```

and here is the method. If you need any more details, just ask!

```
private static double workout(int cat, int totalpacks)
    {
        double percentage;

        percentage = cat / totalpacks * 100;

        return percentage;
    }
```

Comment: because you are doing integer division.

Comment: Can an integer store a decimal value?

Comment: Two words: "Integer Division" Dup of a billion questions here

Comment: My bad for bringing up the same problem!  We all have to start from somewhere.

Comment: @Selman22 It's easy to search for this once you know the answer. Suppose that you don't know the answer. Suppose you are the asker. Imagine searching then.

Comment: Google isn't that effective when you have a paragraph for a question. What's the story with everyone on here being so uptight?

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=why%20does%20division%20return%200%20c%23

Comment: I don't think this is an example of a hard-to-search-for question. It's just a case of knowing how to generalize your problem, which is something very important to learn as you will be doing a lot of Googling in your programming career. Searching for this doesn't require a paragraph or specific details about your program, you already know the division is the problem.

Comment: when I type c# division I can see _c# division returns 0_ in autocomplete box.

Comment: @Selman22 How does the asker know that division is the problem?

Comment: @eddie_cat *You already know the division is the problem*. You and I know that. I'm not sure that the asker knows that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "Calculation returns zero c#" also returns the duplicate question as the first result. That's basically the question title.

Comment: I didn't know if my problem lay with calling the method or somewhere else. I get where your coming from though.

Comment: I just think that the reason this question is asked again and again is that leaner programmers still read arithmetic symbols as they learnt them at school. And at school, never in a million years, would anyone think that `1/2 == 0`. So it takes an enormous leap against the flow of intuition to work out where the problem is. The fact that the question is asked so many times is surely evidence that it is not easy for the asker to solve the problem by themselves.

Comment: And it's pot luck what sort of reaction you get too. Check out this question from January: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188989/simple-calculator-always-return-0

Comment: @DavidHeffernan okey **but**, you know there are thousands of duplicate of this question and you are still answering it instead of marking it duplicate, why?

Comment: @Selman Don't know. Just felt like helping by answering. Helping by closing is also a good choice.  It can be hard to find the right dupe. The one I linked to in my previous comment is quite good. I don't think it does any great harm to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat / totalpacks * 100
```

This expression is evaluated using integer arithmetic. And if `cat` is less than `totalpacks` (assuming both are positive) then `cat / totalpacks` evaluates to zero. You need to force the use of floating point arithmetic. For instance:

```
private static double workout(int cat, int totalpacks)
{
    return (double)cat / totalpacks * 100;
}
```